# Implementation of Focal loss for multi label classification

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

trying to write focal loss for multi-label classification

```
class FocalLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, gamma=2, alpha=0.25):
        self._gamma = gamma
        self._alpha = alpha

    def forward(self, y_true, y_pred):
        cross_entropy_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss(y_true, y_pred)
        p_t = ((y_true * y_pred) +
               ((1 - y_true) * (1 - y_pred)))
        modulating_factor = 1.0
        if self._gamma:
            modulating_factor = torch.pow(1.0 - p_t, self._gamma)
        alpha_weight_factor = 1.0
        if self._alpha is not None:
            alpha_weight_factor = (y_true * self._alpha +
                                   (1 - y_true) * (1 - self._alpha))
        focal_cross_entropy_loss = (modulating_factor * alpha_weight_factor *
                                    cross_entropy_loss)
        return focal_cross_entropy_loss.mean()
```

But when i run this i get

```
  File "train.py", line 82, in <module>
    loss = loss_fn(output, target)
  File "/home/bubbles/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 538, in __call__
    for hook in self._forward_pre_hooks.values():
  File "/home/bubbles/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 591, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'FocalLoss' object has no attribute '_forward_pre_hooks'
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't inherit from `torch.nn.Module` as it's designed for modules with learnable parameters (e.g. neural networks).

Just create normal functor or function and you should be fine.

BTW. If you inherit from it, you should call `super().__init__()` somewhere in your `__init__()`.

### EDIT

Actually inheriting from `nn.Module` might be a good idea, it allows you to use the loss as part of neural network and is common in PyTorch implementations/PyTorch Lightning.